Estimating the Increase in Rademacher Complexity after Feature Selection
I'm trying to estimate how much the Rademacher complexity (or empirical Rademacher complexity) increases when performing feature selection using methods like Sequential Forward Selection or Genetic Algorithms. Given (N) features, the possible combinations (subsets) can explode.
Let's denote the original Rademacher complexity as (R).

What is the estimated increase in the Rademacher complexity after feature selection?
Is there a theoretical or mathematical basis for this increase?

I would appreciate any insights or references to support a more accurate estimation of the increase in Rademacher complexity due to feature selection.
